# If one set A is dense, and another set U is a nonempty open set, then there exists a point A in U.

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, real-numbers

Let A be a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and let U be a nonempty open subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that there exists a point of A in U.

EDIT: Prove directly.

My solution. Since A is a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$, then for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$ there exists a sequence $x_n$ in A such that $x_n$ converges to x. Since U is a nonempty open subset of $\mathbb{R}$, then for every $x\in$U there exists r > 0 such that $I_r(x)$ $\subseteq$ U. Since A is dense, after a while $x_n$ will be inside of the interval $I_r(x)$ and thus in U since $I_r(x)$ $\subseteq$ U.

Comment: Not by contradiction: by definition of convergence, there exists $N$ such that, for $n>N$, $x_n\in I_r(x)$. In particular $x_{N+1}\in I_r(x)$, so $x_{N+1}\in U$.

Comment: So since A is dense, for all x in the reals, there exists a sequence x(n) that converges to x. Suppose that point x is in U. Then x(n+1) is also in U? I am a little confused still.

Comment: Oh I think I see. Since $x_n$ is dense, it must converge to every element in the reals. Since any point in U is also in the reals, it follows that $x_n$ is in $I_r(x)$. Thus by definition of convergence, the next element of the sequence is also in $I_r(x)$, thus in U?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the setup for your contradiction:

> Let $x \in U$ and $r> 0$ be such that $I_r(x)\subset U$.  Now, suppose that $A$ has no points in $U$.  Certainly then, $A$ contains no points in $I_r(x)$.  That is, every point in $a \in A$ satisfies $|a - x| \geq r$.
>
> However, because $A$ is dense, there exists a sequence in $A$ converging to $x$.

Perhaps now you can see where things go wrong.

---

**Direct Proof:** Suppose that $A$ is dense.  Let $x \in U$ and $r> 0$ be such that $I_r(x)\subset U$.  Because $A$ is dense, there is a sequence $x_n$ in $A$ converging to $x$.  By the definition of convergence, this means that there is some $n$ for which $|x_n - x| < r$, which would mean that $x_n \in I_r(x)$, which would mean that $x_n \in U$.

Thus, there is an element of $A$ in $U$.

Comment: So your second to last sentence is true because if its not in $I_r(x)$ its not within the radius of the midpoint x so the difference is bigger than or equal to r? And this is a contradiction since $x_n$ converges to every point in the reals, including things in $I_r(x)$?

Comment: First question, yes.  For the second, it suffices to specifically consider a sequence converging to $x$.

Comment: I am still confused on the latter part. so we have an interval (x-r, x+r) and we know no element of A is in this interval. Thus, $x_n$ cannot converge to x. Thus the contradiction. Since $x\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: But can't it converge to x without getting inside the interval?

Comment: Like if it got closer and closer to x+r but ever actually gets inside of the interval?

Comment: Yes, I'm specifically saying that a sequence cannot converge to $x$ without getting inside the interval.  In other words, if $a_n$ is the sequence, then some $n$ needs to satisfy $|a_n - x| < r$.  This ties in particularly well with the definition of convergence, hence the setup.

Comment: Oh okay, that makes sense. I need to brush up on my understanding of convergence because I did not think that it must be the case that for some n, |$a_n$ - x| < r had to be satisfied.

Comment: You *definitely* need to brush up on your understanding of convergence.  "For every $\epsilon > 0$" includes the case of $\epsilon = r$.

Comment: Oh, right. So it must be the case that it gets infinitely close to the midpoint x in (x-r, x+r). And in this case, it doesn't even get inside the interval at all.

Comment: "Infinitely close" is not a mathematically rigorous thing to say, which is why the definition of convergence has so much stuff going on in it. But yes, that's the right idea.

Comment: I have a proof somewhat extending off this if you wouldn't mind helping me out, maybe in chat?

Comment: If you have another question, make another post.  I don't intend to help you in chat.

Comment: I have just learned that I must prove directly so I will attempt that now.